# Как назвать магическую константу?

Tags: c, code-style

Я написал программу которая читает слово в символьный массив, а затем выводит это слово в обратном порядке, но в связи с тем что индексы массива в языке С нумеруются начиная с нуля, в программе фигурирует единица. Какое имя дать такой магической константе?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ONE_MINUS_ZERO 1

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter word:");
    char word[40] = {0};
    scanf("%s", word);
    int last_index = (int) strlen(word) - ONE_MINUS_ZERO;
    printf("%d\n", last_index);
    for (int i = last_index; i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("%c", word[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: я бы никак не называл. Это часть кода и не может изменится вообще никогда.

Comment: Макрос != константа. Значение макроса подставляется вместо самого макроса, когда препроцессор разбирает ваши файлы. Единственно что тут еще можно сказать, так это то, что если это не библиотека которая будет кем-то использоваться, то имеет смысл подбирать имена макросов исключительно для себя. Однако, такой макрос в данном контексте, я бы вообще выкинул, т.к. мне было бы легче написать `1`  чем вписывать ваш длинный макрос.

Comment: Это не магическая константа и не надо для неё ни имени, ни дефайна.

Comment: А зачем вообще вводить в таком простом случае особую константу? Тем более для одного вхождения :) Добавьте комментарий, если считаете это нужным, и все.

Comment: Я бы больше беспокоился о числе `40`, которое мало того, что взято из головы, так еще и никак не участвует в ограничении размера вводимой строки, что потенциально ведет к повреждению стека.

Comment: исправьте цикл на : `for (int i = strlen(word); i > 0; ) {--i;    printf("%c", word[i]);    }` . И не будет магических констант.

Comment: @AlexGlebe `for (int i = strlen(word); i > 0; printf("%c", word[--i]));`